# Why the police do not keep an eye on Jesse after Hank is attacked?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In Breaking Bad season 3, Hank gets shot after encounter with two Mexicans.
A few days earlier, he was summoned for his actions against Jesse and his badge and gun were taken. Following the attack incident, everyone concedes that it was a mistake and Hank's pursuit of Jesse was not a witch hunt. They also relate the attack with Jesse's incident.

In spite of all we see that Jesse is going everyday to cook meth with Walt.
How does this not come under the radar of the Police Department?
Why are they not keeping an eye on him after Hank is attacked?

Comment: Probably because they do not want to be sued for harassment.

Comment: I think all was pretty sure it had nothing to do with Jesse; it was Cartel.

Comment: After just recently going over the series up to the 4th season, I do not remember them absolving Hank for his pursuit of Jesse.  In fact he loses his badge because he *brutally assaulted* Jesse.  The attack was identified as work of the Mexican Drug Cartel, with the DEA thinking it was related to his investigation in El Paso.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to say "everyone concedes that it was a mistake" (to take Hank's gun).  Marie said it was a mistake,and accused Hank's boss, but she was understandably upset and looking to place blame for her husband's attack.  In fact, Sky was quick to tell Marie just that, and to imply that Marie was placing false blame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a minor plot hole in the series. When two events occur in relatively close proximity to one another, the police would of course investigate to determine if they are indeed connected and to rule that possibility out if they are not. The series doesn't do this as it would have dragged the narrative away from Walter White, the protagonist onto what quickly became a peripheral subject rarely mentioned again.

the series does this again when Jesse later goes to Hank Schrader and makes the videotape where he confesses to his and Walt's roles in the meth business. No one really addresses the fact that Schrader assaulted Jesse so severely that he hospitalized him and that not very much time had passed since this occurred. Jesse would have (and really should have) had serious trust when dealing with Hank from that event; but the series simply hand waves that as it again would have little to to do in advancing the core narrative of Walter White descent  in the final season.

Answer (score 3):

Hank was attacked the same time when Jesse was in hospital. Jesse even dropped the case which can sue Hank. How did they related it to Jesse's incident? It is over-statement.

Jesse was never proved guilty, so why does DEA goes after him when they already have the killer duo brother (One dead and other without legs). I mean they have all their focus in identifying the duo brothers rather than randomly blaming Jesse. Even after the death of Tuco's cousins, they still have two faces to connect to the attack reason not Jesse.